Get single value from MultipartFormDataStreamProvider before processing files (google recaptcha)
In my net framework 4.8 application, I have a route in which it receives form data from the front end. Everything works fine except when there are a large amount of files to process.
The problem is, the app uses Google Recaptcha V3 and the secret key for the Google Recaptcha is generated on the front end then sent to backend in the same request body as all the files. When the network is slow, by the time MultipartFormDataStreamProvider is complete and I have access to the recaptcha token from the front end to do the backend recaptcha validation, it has already been over two minutes and the front end key gets expired, therefore resulting in a failed request.
How can I first extract the recaptcha value somehow from the request body, and then proceed to process the files only after first checking the Google Recaptcha validation and passing the validation check in the backend
Right now, everything will be null until await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider); has been finished, but by the time it is finished when there a large files, RacpatchaKey will have expired.
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("post/files")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        {
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(//somePath);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            try
            {
                MyModel model = BuildMyModel();

                /*************************************************/

                // When there is slow network and large files, by the
                // time it gets here after processing all the files,
                // the RecaptchKey will have expired and validation will fail

                /*************************************************/
                if (!GoogleReCAPTCHA.Validate(model.RecaptchaKey))
                {
                    // return error message
                }

                // ... process rest of data
            }
            ...
         }

         private MyModel BuildMyModel()
         {
            MyModel model = new MyModel();
            model.FirstName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Get("FirstName");
            model.RecaptchaKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Get("RecaptchaKey ");
            ...
            return model;
         }
            


